# Cookies not transfering between pages (JS)

Tags: javascript, cookies

Coockies not transfering beetwen pages. I use JavaScript to specify them. When I write the same thing in the browser console on the page, it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="javascript">
    console.log("js working");
    window.onload = function(){
        console.log("window.onload working");
        console.log('document.getElementsByName("dbname")[0]');
        console.log(document.getElementsByName("dbname")[0]);
        if(typeof(document.getElementsByName("dbname")[0])!="undefined"){
            dbOpts=document.getElementsByName("dbname")[0].getElementsByTagName("option");
            console.log('dbOpts');
            console.log(dbOpts);
            for(i=0;i<dbOpts.length;i++){
                console.log(dbOpts[i].getAttribute("selected")!=null);
                if (dbOpts[i].getAttribute("selected")!=null) dbselectedparam=dbOpts[i].getAttribute("value");
            }
            console.log(dbselectedparam);
            document.cookie = "dbselectedparam="+dbselectedparam+"; path=/";
        }
    }
</script>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Add expiry parameter to the cookie and also ensure that you are running the HTML via a webserver.. with file protocol it does not work :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the [Expires](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) of a cookie, otherwise it will be deleted when you close the browser/navigate away.

here is a great [cookie script from quirksmode](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
```